# How to emulate the Publish action of a web site of Visual Studio in Azure pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, msbuild-task

I am building an Azure Pipeline running on a Windows Self Hosted agent.  The project is an.Net 2.0 web site.  I created a powershell script that connects to our on-prem TFS 2018 server and connect to the TFVC repository, it copies the files to the Agent\s folder.

When in VS2019, I used to Build the solution, right click the main folder and click Publish to copy only required files to the web site’s folder.  I was ending with a clean folder, with no *.cs or extra configuration files.

I am trying to do the same thing with my pipeline.  I currently have this task:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '${{ parameters.solutionToPublishPath }}'
    configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
    restoreNugetPackages: false
    createLogFile: true
    logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'
```

This builds my solution but doesn’t publish it as I used to do in VS2019.  I saw I could use this:

> “msbuildArgs: '/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true
> /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem
> /p:publishUrl="$(build.BinariesDirectory)\"'”

but this doesn’t seem to work, I’m really bad with MsBuild parameters.

After the build, I would want the result of the Publish action in the binaries folder and eventually zip the binaries in the artefact folder, like this:

```
Agent
--- \s
--- --- \depend1
--- --- \depend2
--- --- \portal
--- --- --- \bin\*
--- --- --- \module1\*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx, *.cs
--- --- --- \module2\*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx, *.cs
--- --- --- \*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx, *.cs
--- \b
--- --- \portal
--- --- --- \bin\*
--- --- --- \module1\*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx
--- --- --- \module2\*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx
--- --- --- \*.htm, *.aspx, *.ascx
--- \a
--- --- \portal.zip
```

Do I need to call VSBuild@1 several times ?
Can you help me setting up the MsBuild parameters ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use MSBuild Arguments to compress files to zip, you can use OutputPath, like this:

```
/p:OutputPath=c:\yourdir\output.zip
```

The following are my test and result:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutputPath=c:\testmsbuild\output.zip /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

[image]